# How to export PostgreSQL query result into csv file using windows batch script (without using "\COPY")

Tags: postgresql, powershell, batch-file, export-to-csv, psql

I want to export PostgreSQL query result into csv file using windows batch script (without using "\COPY" because it is creating permission issue). I am currently using below script which executing psql script and writing in file in PIPE("|") delimited format.

`@echo off setlocal set PGPASSWORD='MyPassword' "psql.exe" -h myIP -p myPORT -U myUSER -d myDB -t -o "D:\Test\myfile.csv" -f D:\Raihan\Test\my_sql_script.sql`

SQL file(my_sql_script.sql):
`SELECT ID,NAME from MYTABLE`

The code is writing file (myfile.csv) as pipe delimiter like below with one extra space after each pipe **(Which is another issue I am also facing)**

```
 1| Raihan
 2| Kalu
 3| Param
```

I can easily replace the pipe and space with coma (,) by using below script **but my problem is it is tacking lots of time as it is converting line by line.**

`FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1-2 delims=| " %%I in (D:\Test\myfile.csv) DO echo %%I,%%J >> D:\Test\myfile_2.csv`

Converting millions of data is not possible with this above script on time.

EDIT:
I have used below code

`\COPY (select * from some_table) TO 'D:/tmp/some_file.csv' CSV HEADER;`

which is giving error

`psql:D:/Raihan/Test/test_sql.sql:2: ERROR:  must be superuser to COPY to or from  a file HINT:  Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone. Press any key to continue . . .`

**Note: my DB server is in another server from where I am running the batch file. It will also solve my issue if I could run /COPY without being a superuser.**

Comment: What happens when psql without \copy also creates permission issues?

Comment: What version of Postgres?

Comment: @jjanes it is asking to become a super user which is not possible for me to gain.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver 13.1

Comment: @jjanes I have used below code 
`\COPY (select * from some_table) TO '/tmp/some_file.csv' (format CSV);` which is giving error
 `psql:D:/Raihan/Test/test_sql.sql:2: ERROR:  must be superuser to COPY to or from
 a file
HINT:  Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works
for anyone.
Press any key to continue . . .` Note: my DB server is another server from where i am running the batch file

Comment: Looks like you need to escape the "\" in `\COPY` as it is being stripped and a straight `COPY` is being run. `COPY` is run as the server user and can only name files if run as superuser.  Since you are 13.1 use the `--csv` switch to `psql` to output CSV.

Comment: It looks like the backslash is getting eaten by your shell (or something) before `psql` gets to see it.  Try doubling it, or quoting it, or whatever works for your shell.  You could use --csv, but that will be slower and for large tables will consume much more memory.  Better to fix the actual problem